# AdbMob show white screen

Tags: android

My adb in Activity works good.But when I'm using include.But when I'm using in fragment it's doesn't show.What I doing wrong?

```
  <include
        android:id="@+id/adMob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/elm_adb_mob"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you include a layout? Just create the `AdView` instead of the include.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play).

Comment: the problem that my adbmob show just in one layout.If I want to add my plagin in any other layout it's nothing to show.No any exception,errors.What I'm doing wrong?'<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adMob_bunner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="myunitId" >
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>'